# Transfer disk system to another PC

Tags: windows-10, data-transfer

How can I transfer my W10 disk system with my files and programs (200Gb on classic Sata SSD) to a fresh new PC (new motherboard, new AMD processor, new M2 Nvme disk blank)? Should I install W10 on the new PC first ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You should do a fresh installation of Windows, fresh install of any programs, and then copy data over from the old computer to the new.

This is the best way to set things up on a new computer.

Answer (score 1):

I would do (and do) a fresh install. Why carry old errors forward, as it were.

If you choose to try cloning the system, you will have to re-activate, and since it is a brand new computer, and since the existing license is very likely OEM, it may not even work.

Make the clone, try it, and if it fails, install fresh. That is the best way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that you should do a fresh install of Windows, but you should first make sure to have another HDD or SSD to back everything up to. I would use a different SSD in your new system to install Windows on and then carefully copy everything over from your old SSD. Trying to do everything with your current drive could be risky without all your data safely backed up.